# Access a JS variable inside an html or ejs page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have a js file with JSON object like- 
say main.js

```
const person = {};
person.AGE = '17';
person.GENDER = 'Male';
```

The file is loaded in .ejs file like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
```

Is there any way I can directly access this person variable in HTML or EJS page, say

```
<li></li>
```

I want to write person.GENDER inside li tag.

I know I can have a JS and can use innerHTML and all but is there any way to access directly specifically in .ejs page?

Also, is there a way that I can load my scripts dynamically. Say I have two scripts: ScriptA and ScriptB

Checking some conditions I want to load a particular script. Any idea for doing that?

Comment: Through EJS? I'm afraid that won't be possible. EJS is executed on the server without interacting with the pages JS in it's runtime. Why can you not use `innerHTML`?

Comment: I was just curious to know more and was trying differently

Comment: is that JS-Object on your client side or on the server side?

Comment: one more thing this JS is loaded in script tag of ejs

Comment: It is on client side, while loading the page, this script is loaded initially

Comment: edited the question showing the loading of .js file

Comment: Alright, just what I though, again, EJS sees all your HTML, CSS and JS as Text, all it does is change this text before it's send to the client. You should consider either generating the object on your server or doing it with JS on the client side

Comment: Seems these are two ways and JS on client side will be best I guess. Thank you

Comment: Also, is there any way to load the scripts dynamically, say by checking some conditions I want to load that particular script

Comment: edited the question for script loading.

Comment: That's a completely different question...

Answer (score 0):

> Also, is there a way that I can load my scripts dynamically. Say I have two scripts: ScriptA and ScriptB.
>   Checking some conditions I want to load a particular script. Any idea for doing that?

Do, what EJS was made for:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- head -->
    <% if(condictionA) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
    <% } 
    if (conditionB) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main2.js"></script>
    <% } %>
<!-- head -->
</head>
....
```